# Which scripture is this shloka from? (atamaramo pyrirmak sakshan manmath manmatha)

Tags: scripture, mantras, reference-request, shloka

I am trying to identify which scripture this sloka is from. I came across this sloka in an audiobook:

```
atamaramo pyrirmak sakshan manmath manmatha
आत्मारामों प्यरीरमक साक्षण मन्मथ मन्मथा
```

researching online didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although slightly different, the first part occurs as the last part of [verse 10.29.42 of the Bhagavata Purana](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/29/42/);

> श्रीशुक उवाच
> इति विक्लवितं तासां श्रुत्वा योगेश्वरेश्वर: ।
> प्रहस्य सदयं गोपीरात्मारामोऽप्यरीरमत् ॥ ४२ ॥
> śrī-śuka uvāca
> iti viklavitaṃ tāsāṃ śrutvā yogeśvareśvaraḥ | 
> prahasya sa-dayaṃ gopīr **ātmārāmo'py arīramat** || 42 ||
>
> ātma ārāmaḥ — self-satisfied; 
> api — even though; 
> arīramat — He satisfied.
>
> Śukadeva Gosvāmī said: Smiling upon hearing these despondent words from the gopīs, Lord Kṛṣṇa, the supreme master of all masters of mystic yoga, mercifully enjoyed with them, **although He is self-satisfied.**

The latter part is the last part of [verse 10.32.2](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/32/2/):

> तासामाविरभूच्छौरि: स्मयमानमुखाम्बुज: ।
> पीताम्बरधर: स्रग्वी साक्षान्मन्मथमन्मथ: ॥ २ ॥
> tāsām āvirabhūc chauriḥ smayamāna-mukhāmbujaḥ |
> pītāmbara-dharaḥ sragvī **sākṣān manmatha-manmathaḥ** || 2 ||
>
> sākṣāt — directly; 
> man-matha — of Cupid (who bewilders the mind); 
> man — of the mind; 
> mathaḥ — the bewilderer.
>
> Then Lord Kṛṣṇa, a smile on His lotus face, appeared before the gopīs. Wearing a garland and a yellow garment, **He directly appeared as one who can bewilder the mind of Cupid**, who himself bewilders the minds of ordinary people.